# How to use FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID() in sql code for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote some code to extract data from HR tables for a letter to be produced out of Oracle. When I run this code it will prompt for 2 parameters.

1. Attribute20 (DFF stored on the HR person record) which stores the a YEAR value (i.e. 2020)
2. Review_date which I have set a to_Char on so that the same value gets populated as for the first parameter (i.e. 2020)

When I run the code out of TOAD I initialize first by running:

exec fnd_global.apps_initialize(1825, 50648, 800);

This is the code I run the extract the required data:

```
          select          
          pp.person_id,
          fu.EMPLOYEE_ID,
          fu.user_id,          
          pp.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
          pp.title,
          pp. first_name,
          pp.middle_names,
          pp.last_name,   
          pp.full_name,  
          paaf.assignment_id, 
          paaf.ass_attribute10 business_unit,    
          dep.description department,
          pp.EMAIL_ADDRESS email,
          peef.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID,
          peef.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE,
          peef.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE,
          peef.ASSIGNMENT_ID,
          peef.ELEMENT_LINK_ID,
          peef.ELEMENT_TYPE_ID,
          peef.ATTRIBUTE20 financial_year,       
          peef.DATE_EARNED,
          peevf.screen_entry_value bonus_amount,
          to_char(pprv.REVIEW_DATE, 'YYYY') perf_review_Date,
          pprv.RATING_MEANING individual_perf_score,
          pprv.ATTRIBUTE19 organization_perf_score                     
          from 
          per_all_people_f pp,
          fnd_user fu,
          per_all_assignments_f paaf,
          pay_Element_entries_f peef,
          pay_element_entry_Values_f peevf,
          PER_PERFORMANCE_REVIEWS_V pprv,
          gl_code_combinations gcc,
         (select flex_value, description
          from   FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL ffvv
          where  ffvv.flex_value_set_id =  1009629)dep 
          where 
           pp.PERSON_ID = paaf.PERSON_ID(+)   
      and  pp.PERSON_ID = pprv.PERSON_ID(+)
      and  pp.person_id(+) = fu.employee_id
      and  fu.USER_ID(+) = FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID()
      and  paaf.ASSIGNMENT_ID = peef.ASSIGNMENT_ID(+)
      and  peef.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID = peevf.ELEMENT_ENTRY_ID(+)
      and  paaf.DEFAULT_CODE_COMB_ID = gcc.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
      and  gcc.SEGMENT3 = dep.flex_value     
      and  sysdate between paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and paaf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
      and  sysdate between pp.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and pp.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE     
      --and  peef.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE and peef.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
      and  peef.element_link_id in (7064, 7172, 7183, 8103)  ---performance bonus element entry 
      and  peef.ATTRIBUTE20 = :p_fin_year --financial year     --
      and  to_char(pprv.REVIEW_DATE, 'YYYY') = :p_fin_year  --performance review date --
      order by pp.last_name;
```

The data extracted is correct.

The code I have populated into Oracle Reports and I have registered both the execution and the concurrent program which points to this oracle report. This report I have defined with two parameters:

1. User id which links to a value set with a default type of profile on USER_ID. So basically what this allows for is when a user logs on the system is automatically initialized for user_id, responsibility_id and application_id. So in this case if I log on my user_id (being the FND_GLOBAL.USER_ID()) will pull though and default in as the user id for this report. The correct value is pulling through.
2. Financial year which ties back to the code's p_fin_year for user to enter the financial year (i.e. 2020)

I am at a loss as to why when the report is run out of Oracle it returns no data but the same code does extract data out of Toad??

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify your problem! [mcve].

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: This is Oracle Apps., right? If so, did you try to do *initialization* (I mean, to call `exec fnd_global.apps_initialize(1825, 50648, 800);`) within the report itself, in its **After parameter form** trigger?

Comment: Are there any implicit type conversions in the query? Anything that might depend on a session setting like NLS_DATE_FORMAT, that could be different for different clients?